# Problem with running .NET Core 3.1 application in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I installed Visual Studio 2022 and created a new ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API application.

The app builds fine however when I try to run it on kestrel throws an error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Nie można odnaleźć określonego pliku.'

The error does not occur when running from CLI by 'dotnet run'.
The error also does not run when running in Rider IDE.

Below commands and results:

```
dotnet --version 
8.0.100

--list-sdks
3.1.426 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
8.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.32 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.25 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 8.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.32 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.25 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 8.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.32 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.25 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 8.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

Visual Studio is installed in:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
```

Any thoughts how to repair that?

Comment: .NET Core 3.1 reached End Of Life a year ago. Why are you using it at all? The oldest supported .NET (Core) version is 6. The error itself shows you tried to use a .NET 6 assembly but that doesn't work because .NET 6 SDK isn't installed

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for the answer.
I am trying to run huge application written in .net 3.1 and I am getting that error.
To be sure it is no related to that project I created a new one and I am getting the same error.
To simplify I wrote that I am creating a new one because I believe it does not matter.

Comment: Yeah, I would try changing the app to target appropriate .NET version in project properties and make sure that the SDK chosen is installed on your machine.

Comment: @tylkonachwile you're getting that error because the .NET Core 3 SDK isn't installed and whatever you did, you ended up using a .NET 6 library, perhaps because you added a NuGet package version that targets .NET 6 or later. NuGet package authors started removing support for .NET Core 3.1 as soon as it reached End Of Life. EF Core 6 for example, only supports .NET 6 and later.

Answer (score 1):

You are using 6.0.0 version of .Net for this library **System.IO**
You also want to run 3.0.0 version of Netcore in your project.

- First make sure if you have .netCore SDK version of 6.0.0 ,If it's not  Download .netCore SDK from Microsoft Web site

**The Problem is package mismatch** . If you want to work with 3.0.0 version  Netcore in a project ,all your libraries and packages must be compatiple with this version.

For instance ,you can not download any package from nuget with version 6.0.0 or your MVC project can not be 6.0.0

But In your situation  ,you are using  6.0.0 version with **System.IO** Library

If you make all your packages compatible with the same version, the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the NuGet cache might cause conflicts. Try clearing the NuGet cache by running the following command in the terminal:

```
dotnet nuget locals all --clear
```